# Como Restar numeros digitados en una cadena de texto entre una oracion en Java

Tags: java, string

Necesito saber restar unos números digitados por el usuario pero en cadena de texto, ejemplo: “Pedro tiene 5, manzanas regala 2, y se come 1, ¿Cuantas manzanas le quedan?”, mi sistema debe identificar esos números dentro de la oración y restarlos, Eh estado intentado con varias funciones y cosas, pero no lo eh logrado:/ estuve intentando usar la funcion split, pongo el ";" despues de cada numero, para que pueda reconocerlo y hacer la respectiva operacion, pero me da error

```
   String oracion = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Digite la oracion");       
    if(oracion.contains("come")
    {
         String oracion="";
         String[] arr = oracion.split(";");
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Integer.valueOf(arr[0]) - Integer.valueOf(arr[1]));
        return null;
         
    }
```

Comment: Sería conveniente que indicaras qué es lo que has intentado, mostrando el código correspondiente, y qué resultados o errores has tenido. También sería bueno que aclararas un poco más lo que quieres conseguir. Por ejemplo, ¿qué pasa si la oración es "Juan se comió un pastel de los 6 que tenía"? ¿Esperas que el programa pueda interpretar esa frase? ¿O habría alguna limitación a la estructura de las oraciones?

Comment: En cuanto a lo de las oraciones, lo tengo, porque las reconoce con indexOf o Contains,  reconoce palabras como "agrega", eso seria suma y "quita" seria como resta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La mejor opción es hacerlo mediante expresiones regulares, porque a diferencia de la otra respuesta, si trabajas con números que posean más de un digito no fracasará el calculo.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class MyClass {


    public static void main(String args[]) {
      String phrase = "Pedro tiene 50, manzanas regala 20, y se come 5";
      Integer result = null;
      Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
      Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(phrase);
      while(matcher.find()) {
          if(result == null){
              // first match
              result = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group());
          }else{
              // others match
              result = result - Integer.parseInt(matcher.group());
              
          }
      }

        String output = result == null ? "No hay numeros en la oración" : String.valueOf(result);
        System.out.println(output);
    }
}
```

La lógica y el patrón es bastante sencillo, defines un valor inicial para tu resultado (`null`) que servirá como bandera para saber cuando se identifica el primer numero o no hay ninguno dentro de la oración.
Luego de eso, simplemente va buscando y recorriendo los match de la expresión aplicando la lógica que gustes.

Comment: Eres un crack bro, me resolviste lo que exactamente necesitaba, gracias

Answer (score 1):

Para sacar números de un string he hecho algo sencillo:

```
String frase = "khdkasjh 8 dklasdlj 4 dfdsf";
    String num = "";
    char [] frase_div = frase.toCharArray();
    for(int i=0; i<frase_div.length; i++) {
        if(Character.isDigit(frase_div[i])){
            num+=frase_div[i];
        }
    }
    System.out.println(num);
```

Bueno y te explico como funciona, partiendo de que tienes un string lo convierto a un array del tipo char `char[] frase_div = frase.toCharArry();` para así poder comparar carácter a carácter. y bueno luego un bucle for con un if dentro para saber si el carácter es un digito con la funcion `Character.isDigit(frase_div[i])` luego he metido los números a un mismo string pero espero te valga para implementarlo a tu código o de inspiración

Comment: Muchas gracias bro, me ayudaste, ahora intentare, sumarlos o restarlos, que es lo unico que me falta, pero me echaste una mano, te lo agradezco